# Module registered in IIS7 doens't work

Tags: iis-7, httpmodule

I've created a small Class Library, with a HttpModule that uses a filter to add some html to every requested page served by IIS7.

I tested it first by registering the module in the web.config in a test web site, and it works as it should, but only in that one application.

I generated a dll, and created a strong named assembly.

I need to somehow add this assembly as a module in IIS on a server level, so that it works for all requests, on all applications, and for non-asp.net content as well.

So far, I have tried adding the .dll as a native module. This doesn't work. It's on the list of native modules, but it doesn't work.

I have installed the .dll in the GAC.

Reading on, it seems I have to add the assembly as a managed module, and then choose it in the dropdown list under "add managed module" in IIS.

For this, I tried using the commandline tool appcmd, writing: "add module /name: string /type: string /preCondition: string"

I've had no success doing this, since I can't figure out what to set as type and precondition.

As I have read, the modules registered in IIS should work for all applications in all sites, and all requests.

The point is to avoid having to register the module in every applications web.config file.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/244/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline/

Comment: I've edited my answer with more help how to use appcmd command. Don't add it as native module, if you struggle with command line use IIS Manager to add **Managed Module**, steps how in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After working with this for a bit, I managed to make it work.

Installing the assembly in the .net 4.0 GAC will not make it available in the type dropdown in IIS manager under "Add Managed Module".

What  I had to do was:

Create the .net 4.0 Class Library, and compile it as a strong named assembly

Install it in the .net 4.0 GAC by using the gacutil, located in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

(Or make Visual Studio compile, sign and install the assembly automatically)

Add this line under `<modules>` in applicationHost.config: (it has to be done manually, it can't be done in the manager)

```
<add name="MyName" type="NameSpace.ClassName" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

This makes the module run on requests to sites developed in .net 4.

It appears, however, that requests to sites developed in pre .net 4 versions can't use a module created in .net 4.0. So if you make requests for pages in a site created in .net 3.5, the module will not work.

**Another observation:**

After you have added the module to IIS via the applicationHost.config file, if you open the IIS manager, highlight the servername in connections and click modules. You will see the .net 4 module on the list.

Double click on it, and you'll then see the settings for it. You'll see that the "Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers" checkbox is checked. If you uncheck it, and hit ok, you'll get an error saying that the assembly hasn't been installed in the GAC.

But didn't I just install it succesfully in the .net 4 GAC? And didn't I just see the module run in a request?

If you go ahead and save the settings anyway, you get a runtime error, and if you look in applicationHost.config, you'll see that your previously manually added module settings has changed.

But what if I want to "Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers?

Comment: Thanks, Soeren, it was a lot of help reading your question and answers you put here yourself. I have a question about the next steps. How would you put a configuration file for you module? (as it is running with no specific application). I mean, what is the standard way to put some kind of configuration file for such a server-level module?

Comment: Hi, your seems useful to me but where is this applicationHost.config file you are talking about... I am also facing a similar issue...

Answer (score 5):

I am now able to run the module on every request. The reason it didn't work before was a totally un-related error on my part.
So, the steps involved to make it work is:

1. Write the code you want to run on every request, as a .net 3.5 Class Library.
2. Compile it as a strong-named assembly.
3. Install the assembly in the GAC.
4. In IIS7 manager, select the server name in connections, click Modules, click "Add managed module" in actions.
5. write a name for the module and choose your newly installed assembly in the type dropdown.
6. Make sure the site uses an application pool running in integrated mode.

Of course, it's not always a good idea to let all code run on all requests, so you may need to filter some of the requested files.

**One question remains though!**

There are now two GAC's, Microsoft.NET for .net 4.0, and Windows GAC for pre .net 4.0.
Because I created my assembly in .net 3.5, it was installed in Windows GAC, and therefore it was available in the type dropdown in IIS manager.

When I created my assembly in .net 4.0, it was installed in the Microsoft.NET GAC, and as a result, it was NOT available in the type dropdown in IIS manager.

The question is: How do you add a .net 4.0 assembly as a managed module in IIS7, and have it run like my 3.5 managed module?

This must be possible, right?

Comment: The version of IIS Manager shipped with IIS 7 was built on .NET 3.5. Thus, it would not be able to load anything from .NET 4 GAC.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a module at a server level. You can do that from command line:

```
appcmd add module /name:string /type:string /preCondition:string
```

To get command line help execute: `appcmd add module /?`
In short, it must look like:

```
appcmd add module /name:AnyNameOfYourChoice /type:YourClassNameSpace.YourClassName
```

`/preContition` parameter is optional.

More details [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754939%28WS.10%29.aspx).

OR

Do it from IIS Manager by going to server node -> Modules -> Add Managed Module
More details [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/366/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework/). (bottom of the page)

Comment: Thanks. As you have noticed, I edited my question a couple of times cause I wanted to be as specific as possible. I will try out your suggestions and get back.

Comment: The assembly is now added as a managed module, and now I get an error saying: "System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type..." which suggests that the dll can't be found. Does the dll need to be located in a specific place? I've copied it to the "inetsrv" folder. The assembly is also installed in GAC.

Comment: Can you try to add it through IIS Manager?

Comment: If I use gacutil to install the assembly to the GAC, it ends up in another GAC folder (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL) since it is a .NET 4.0 project. However, it seems that, in order for the assembly to be available in the "add managed module" dropdown in IIS manager, it must be in the original windows GAC folder (%windir%\assembly). gacutil might tell you that the assembly is installed correctly in the GAC, but it is in the "wrong" folder. So now I have to find a way to move it, or install it in the correct GAC folder, and you cannot simply copy it there.

Comment: Ok, so now I tried creating the class library in .NET 3.5 and compile a strong named assembly out of that. This assembly installs in the Windows GAC and is available to add as a managed module in IIS7, using the IIS manager. However, the module still doesn't run on requests. The html is not added to the requested pages.

Comment: Am I right that you managed to get it working for single Website when configured in Web.config?

Comment: Yes, if I add the module in web.config and test in IIS express, it works.